# .htaccess remove .php and add url parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I have this URL `http://localhost/signUp.php?url={somevalue}`
I want to convert it to be like this:

```
http://localhost/signUp/{somevalue}
```

how can I do this to all pages not just signUp.php using .htaccess?

I already found out how to remove .php but I didn't know how to add a parameter.

```
#Remove .php from url
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Are there any restrictions to "somevalue", or can it literally be _anything_ (except for a slash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have other requirements, you don't need to "remove" `.php` as a separate rule. You have `/signUp/{somevalue}` that must rewrite to `/signUp.php?url={somevalue}`.

This can be achieved with a rule like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(signUp)/([^/.])+$ $1.php?url=$2 [L]
```

Providing you restrict `somevalue` to not contain dots or slashes, there's no need to check that the request does not map to a file. And this is unlikely to map to a directory unless `/signUp` also exists as a directory.

`somevalue` must contain 1 or more characters. If you have further restrictions then this should be included in the regex.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks but this works only on signup, how i can make it work on all pages?

Assuming "all pages" consists of single path segments from the document root of 4 or more characters, containing just the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen) then change the above `RewriteRule` like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]{4,})/([^/.])+$ $1.php?url=$2 [L]
```

This does check that the corresponding `.php` file exists before rewriting the request, although that may not be strictly necessary if you have no other directives.

Comment: Thanks but this works only on signup, how i can make it work on all pages?